# LibTIFF.NET convert tiled OJPEG to single tile image

Tags: libtiff.net

We can observe that tiled OJPEG tiff files cannot be decompressed correctly. Is there any smart way to create a single tile interim file first?

Answer (score 0):

It is quite likely that the people who implemented OJPEG support didn't have a tiled image to test with.

OJPEG is a format that is basically broken by design, so support for it in libtiff is minimal.